# Filterpy Kalman Filter batch processing with multiple measurement sources

Tags: kalman-filters, smoothing

In pythons module for kalman-filtering, filterpy, there is a function `batch_filter()` to batch filter a list of measurements that then can be used for RTS-smoothing. [See the documentation here.](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/filterpy/latest/filterpy.pdf)

I want to smooth my measurements with a RTS-smoother like:

```
(mu, cov, _, _) = kf.batch_filter(list(np.array(centroids)))
(x, P, K, Pp) = kf.rts_smoother(mu, cov)
```

The problem is now that I have two measurements from two different sources with different measurement noises. The function `batch_filter()` can only process one source of measurements. When I calculate and save x and P for every time step with the sequence "predict, update with R1, update with R2", is this the same thing `batch_filter()` would do?

Answer (score 1):

I am not use how you can success multiple sensors using batch filter, but, in sequential filtering you need to perform time update before each measurement. You can do it using the timetag information of each sensor measurement. You can modify the batch filter code however, I strongly recommend to write your own function depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Processing two different sources with a single filter is not possible. As I understand you want to get single clean signal by using n noisy observations but Kalman filter it is not a dimension reduction method so you will get vector/scalar state from vector/scalar observations in same dimensions. After filtering noisy observations individually you should find another way to combine them. I also agree with the previous answer, you may want to implement Kalman filter by yourself. It is relatively simple. I can recommend this paper: 
"Understanding the Basis of the Kalman Filter Via a Simple and Intuitive Derivation" from Ramsey Faragher.